# Item in array getting deleted from top only

Tags: reactjs

I have an array off which I would like to delete elements upon clicking the delete button. However, the problem with this is that only the data at the gets deleted no matter where I click leaving the data at that index intact. I would like to know what I can do to ensure this works normally. Below is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Task = () => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setTodos(data)
            })
    }, []);

    //Using splice
    // const deleteTodo = (index) => {
    //     const temp = [...todos];
    //     temp.splice(index, 1);
    //     setTodos(temp);
    //     console.log(index);
    //     // console.log(`newData : ${arr} || newLength : ${arr.length}`);
    //     console.log(`newLength : ${todos.length}`);
    // }

    //Using Filter
    const deleteTodo = (index) => {
        const newTodo = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== index);
        setTodos(newTodo);
        console.log(`newLength : ${todos.length}`);
    }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <table className='table'>
                <tbody>
                    {todos.map((key, value) => (
                        <tr key={key.id}>
                            <td>{todos[value].id}</td>
                            <td>{todos[value].title}</td>
                            <td>{`${todos[value].completed}`}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button className='btn btn-danger ' onClick={() => deleteTodo(key)}> Delete </button>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button className='btn btn-primary'>Add Task</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Task;
```

I have tried both the splice and the filter methods.
The splice method deletes data only off the top irrespective of the data I delete whereas the filter method doesn't do anything at all as shown on the snippet below. The length remains the same even after clicking the delete button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.map()` method the first argument - current array item, the second - index. You pass the current array item to your `deleteTodo` func, instead of passing `id` (`deleteTodo(key.id)`).

It should be like this:

```
    const deleteTodo = (index) => {
        const newTodo = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== index);
        setTodos(newTodo);
        console.log(`newLength : ${todos.length}`);
    }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <table className='table'>
                <tbody>
                    {todos.map((key, value) => (
                        <tr key={key.id}>
                            <td>{todos[value].id}</td>
                            <td>{todos[value].title}</td>
                            <td>{`${todos[value].completed}`}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button className='btn btn-danger ' onClick={() => deleteTodo(key.id)}> Delete </button>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button className='btn btn-primary'>Add Task</button>
        </div>
    );
```

Also you don't need to do `todos[value]` as you already have a current item.

You could use this:

```
todos.map((item, index) => (<>
<td>{item.id}</td>
<td>{item.title}</td>
</>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `map()` index (which is independent to your to-dos), use the to-do `id` returned by the API, like so:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Task = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setTodos(data);
      });
  }, []);

  //Using Filter
  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    const newTodo = todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
    setTodos(newTodo);
    console.log(`newLength : ${todos.length}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <table className="table">
        <tbody>
          {todos.map((todo) => (
            <tr key={todo.id}>
              <td>{todo.id}</td>
              <td>todo.title}</td>
              <td>{`${todo.completed}`}</td>
              <td>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-danger "
                  onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}
                >
                  {" "}
                  Delete{" "}
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Add Task</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Task;
```

[image: Edit angry-fast-upe615]